# How to separate the prefix in words that are 'di'?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string, string-matching

I want to separate some prefixes that are integrated into words after the word "di" is followed by letters.

```py
sentence1 = "dipermudah diperlancar"
sentence2 = "di permudah di perlancar"
```

I expect the output like this:

```py
output1 = "di permudah di perlancar"
output2 = "di permudah di perlancar"
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cBO5gw/1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This expression might work to some extent:

```
(di)(\S+)
```

if our data would just look like as simple as is in the question. Otherwise, we would be adding more boundaries to our expression.

#### Test

```
import re    
regex = r"(di)(\S+)"    
test_str = "dipermudah diperlancar"    
subst = "\\1 \\2"    

print(re.sub(regex, subst, test_str))
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/p9ZP1A/1), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/p9ZP1A/1debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to do this using `re.sub`:

```
sentence1 = "adi dipermudah diperlancar"
output = re.sub(r'(?<=\bdi)(?=\w)', ' ', sentence1)
print(output)
```

Output:

```
adi di permudah di perlancar
```

The idea here is to insert a space whenever what immediately precedes is the prefix `di`, and what also follows is some other word character.